# checking out Visual Studio 2017 files through node scripts

Tags: node.js, npm, visual-studio-2017, task-runner-explorer

I'm using node through Visual Studio task runner explorer to copy files from node_modules (xxx.min.js files) to the wwwroot of an ASP.NET core application. If the file is already checked in I get an error. I want to check out a Visual Studio project file if it already exists and if it is not already checked out. How can I do this with node?

In my package.json file I export a scripts command which I run through the task runner explorer.

```
{
  "version": "6.0.0",
  "name": "domain.basisarchitectuur.web",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
  "jquery": "^1",
   "jquery-ui-1-11-1": "^1.11.1",
   "underscore": "^1.6.0",
   "bootstrap": "^3.3.4"
 },
 "scripts": {
   "expose-vendor-scripts": "node .\\node\\copy-vendor-scripts-to-wwwroot.js"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use npm package 'tfs' and otherwise you can 'shelljs' to execute any command that you would execute in command prompt.